# R: finding Kendall distance between two rankings

Tags: r

```
library(RMallow)
seq1 = do.call("rbind", list(c(1, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 5.5, 7.5, 7.5)))
seq2 = do.call("rbind", list(c(1.5, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 6, 7, 8)))
seq1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    1  2.5  2.5    4  5.5  5.5  7.5  7.5
seq2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]  1.5  1.5    3  4.5  4.5    6    7    8
AllKendall(seq1, seq2)
Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
In addition: Warning message:
In sweep(data.info, 2, seqs.info, "-") :
  STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'
```

I am using the `AllKendall` function from the package `RMallow`. However, I ran into an error trying to calculate the Kendall's distance between those 2 sequences. Does this function only work for more than 2 rankings? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the `AllKendall()` function, it states that it computes all of the Kendall distances between two different sets of rankings. A list of 1-8 is merely a ranking of 8 objects, not a *set* of rankings. In order words, `AllKendall()` from the `RMallow` package is expecting you to pass a set of matrices.

Example: (will return a matrix of all possible combinations of Kendall distances)

```
#expanded on seq1 and seq2

seq3 = do.call("rbind", list(c(1, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 5.5, 7.5, 7.5), c(5,6,7,8,4,3,2,1)))
seq4 = do.call("rbind", list(c(1.5, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 6, 7, 8), c(8,1,7,2,6,3,5,4)))
AllKendall(seq3, seq4)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0   14
[2,]   21   14
```

If you are only trying to compare one pair of rankings, I'd recommend using the `Kendall()` function from the `Kendall` package.

```
#your original sequences
seq1 = do.call("rbind", list(c(1, 2.5, 2.5, 4, 5.5, 5.5, 7.5, 7.5)))
seq2 = do.call("rbind", list(c(1.5, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 6, 7, 8)))
```

It's worth pointing out that just running the `Kendall` function won't actually give you the Kendall distance

```
Kendall(seq1, seq2)
tau = 0.902, 2-sided pvalue =0.004694
```

Rather you must save the `Kendall` object and call each piece individually.

```
k <- Kendall(seq1, seq2) #from 'Kendall' package

k$tau #Kendall’s tau statistic
[1] 0.9021342
attr(,"Csingle")
[1] TRUE

k$sl #two-sided p-value
[1] 0.004693985
attr(,"Csingle")
[1] TRUE

k$S #Kendall score
[1] 23
attr(,"Csingle")
[1] TRUE

k$D #denominator, tau=S/D
[1] 25.4951
attr(,"Csingle")
[1] TRUE

k$varS #variance of S
[1] 60.54762
attr(,"Csingle")
```

Comment: Could you enlighten me with the Kendall objects dear? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216252/kendall-tau-kendall-score